# German-French false friends dictionary

Tags: french, false-friends

I would like to know if there is a German-French dictionary of false friends, i.e. words that exist in both languages and sound similarly but have different meanings, for example état in French means "state" and Etat in German means "budget". I was able to find similar dictionaries for German and Hungarian, German and Polish etc, but so far no German-French one.

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t understand the close votes on behalf of being **too broad**. How is “Is there a dictionary of false friends for the language pair French-German?” too broad? Are there that many dictionaries of false friends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_falscher_Freunde#Franz%C3%B6sisch)

Some other hits in the internet:

- https://www.problem-hilfe.de/franzoesisch/h.php/Faux_Amis/nicht_existent.html
- http://www.castel-franc.com/blog/faux-amis-falsche-freunde